# Will a HCMOS output TCXO work with LPC1114?

Tags: lpc

I am planning to use the output from a FOX924B 10 MHz TCXO with HCMOS output as an input to the 32 bit counter of LPC 1114 (not the XTAL input, but to CT32B0_CAP0 pin). I have the following questions:

(1) The datasheet for FOX924B just says HCMOS output. Does it imply square wave output?
(2) Can I directly route the output from the TCXO to the CT32B0_CAP0 pin of LPC1114?

Would much appreciate your replies!
Abhishek

Answer (score 2):

"HCMOS output" implies that a low level will be no more than 0.3Vcc, and that a high level will be no less than 0.7Vcc. This is compatible with any CMOS input with a supply of Vcc, and if Vcc is 3.3V or higher then also with any TTL or LVTTL input.

All crystal oscillators (but not bare crystals) generate square waves; for rise and fall times and duty cycle check the datasheet.

Comment: Thanks!, but what I intended to ask is that crystal oscillators also have other kinds of output, like clipped sine wave, sine wave, etc. So when the datasheet just says "HCMOS" output, does it imply a square wave output?

Comment: No, it merely makes guarantees about what "high" and "low" are. The fact that it's an oscillator that doesn't specify other output forms implies that it generates a square wave.

Comment: Thanks!, one another question, the pin capacitance for the LPC1114 microcontroller is 2.8 pF (max, as per datasheet). As per datasheet of the TCXO, the output load is 15pF (max). So I guess I can connect the TCXO output directly to the microcontroller? Or do I need to put any pull-down resistors or other stuff?

Comment: Normal HCMOS outputs actively drive the line, so you don't need to pull it either way.